# It says 1 of 2 branches missed in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 3 classes. I am trying to set a variable in the main method through an object called "main" and reuse that value by writing super.getnumberofsets(); in the for loop but it says "1 of 2 branches missed".

```
 public static void main(){

//in the main method

//Main class maintain the private variables with their setters and getters.


 Main main = new Main();

 Sets sets = new Sets();


System.out.print("Enter how many sets you want to create: ");

newnumberofsets = in.nextInt();

main.set_numberofsets(newnumberofsets);

sets.setgroups();

sets.getgroups();

}

// in Sets class


protected void setgroups()

{

        //In this loop it says "1 of 2 branches missed".

        for(int x = 0; x<super.getnumberofsets();x++) { 
        main_zeroarray[x] = new Main0();
    }       
}

protected void getgroups() {
    count = 1;

    for(int x = 0 ;x < super.getnumberofsets();x++) {
        System.out.println(count + ". Set " + setnames[x]);
        count++;
    }

}
```

I expected that the super keyword would read the same value from the object main.set_newnumberofsets(newnumberofsets);

Comment: Are you getting an `Exception` when you run your code? Are you getting a compilation error when Eclipse compiles your code?

Comment: @Abra - There is no compiling error but when I assign the value for example 5 it should print 5 statements but it doesn't do that and I would add the other function to give you the full picture. then you can re-read the code.

Comment: _when I assign the value for example 5 it should print 5 statements_ Are you referring to the loop in method `getgroups()` in the code appearing in your question?

Comment: yes the getgroups();

Comment: Quite obviously, from the code you posted, `super.getnumberofsets()` is not returning the value you expect it to. Unfortunately you have not posted a [mcve], so all I can suggest is try to debug your code in order to see when and where the value changes.

Comment: I would try to make simple minimal reproducible example and add it or edit the code of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation of there being a missed branch in the lopp is that that `super.getnumberofsets()` returns `0`, so the loop terminating condition `x < super.getnumberofsets()` is `false`, thus the loop increment `x++` is never executed, making it a "missed branch".